# Is there a Shia book that analyses all Sunni hadeeth or raavi (narrator of hadees)

Tags: uloom-al-hadith, shia-sunni, ilm-ar-rijal

Asalam-o-alekum,
Is there any Shia book which analyses individual hadees in Sunni's 6 books and has some comments like whether this hadees is acceptable by Shia scholars or not? And similarly is there a Shia book which lists all Sunni raavis which are rejected by Shia's with some reasoning?
If such book is available in Arabic, Urdu and English then please let me know.

Thanks
Lateef

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: As Shi'a consider most of the Sahaba as untrustworthy it sounds rather unlikely that they will go further checking other narrators in narrator chains.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are many books on this subject.
Book "الصحیحان فی المیزان"; Its author is Seyyed Ali Hosseini Milani and its publisher is the Center for Islamic Facts.
Book; It examines and researches the two books of Sahih Muslim and Sahih Bukhari and some of their narrations, in order to clarify that everything in these two books is narrated.

https://www.ghbook.ir/index.php?name=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D8%AD%D9%8A%D8%AD%D8%A7%D9%86%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%85%D9%8A%D8%B2%D8%A7%D9%86&option=com_dbook&task=readonline&book_id=4796&page=1&chkhashk=18A0AD00E3&Itemid=218&lang=fa&tmpl=component

Answer (score 0):

There are books that want to critique the hadiths quoted in Sunni books or to study a document. But they have been looked at thematically.
For example, the book Siri Dar Sahihin is written by Mohammad Sadegh Najmi, who in a research in a fair critique and with a comprehensive study, has shown the weaknesses of two books of Sahih Six. Of course, he points out that there are undoubtedly authentic hadiths in these two books, but there are also many narrations that contradict the certain principles of the Qur'an as well as other authentic hadiths. So he has examined them.
The book of the best creation of God: The Attributes of the Commander of the Faithful (pbuh) in the language of the Sunni shaykhs, written by Abdul Rahim Mubarak, is a summary of hadiths and narrations that speak only in a wonderful way of divine grace towards the Commander of the Faithful (pbuh).

Numerous books in Persian have critiqued the hadiths of the Sunni Sahih Seth thematically. But it was difficult for me to find books in Arabic or English on the subject.

https://bookroom.ir/book/44213/%D8%B3%DB%8C%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B5%D8%AD%DB%8C%D8%AD%DB%8C%D9%86-%D8%A8%D8%B1%D8%B1%D8%B3%DB%8C-%D8%AF%D9%88-%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D9%88-%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%B1%DA%A9-%D9%85%D9%87%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%84-%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%AA-%D8%B5%D8%AD%DB%8C%D8%AD-%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D8%B1%DB%8C-%D9%88-%D8%B5%D8%AD%DB%8C%D8%AD-%D9%85%D8%B3%D9%84%D9%85

http://ketabesabz.com/book/18124/%D8%AF%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%84%D9%88%D8%AF-%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8-%D8%AE%D8%AF%D8%A7-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D8%B5%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AD-%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%87-%D8%A7%D9%87%D9%84-%D8%B3%D9%86%D8%AA